# How to use object array in other file in the same package?

Tags: java, oop

This is file *theArray.java*

```
public class theArray<E> {
    private Object[] arr;
    public void add(E item){
    //adding new element method omitted
}
```

This is the other file named *Calculate.java* (which is in the same package with *theArray.java*)

```
public class Calculate {
    //I want to bring the Object array arr that I made in file theArray.java but syntax is really confusing.

}
```

How can I resolve these problems?

Comment: *if i call function arr.add(E item) in Calculate.java, I tried to do arithmetic operation with added element in array. however, type casting E to int is not working.* -- Can you show us what you've tried? Add a getter for `arr`.

Comment: @NicholasK oh, actually I solved type casting E to int problem. thank you very much.

Comment: Type casting E to int? That array variable is private so it can't be accessed without a getter as @NicholasK suggested, and type casting to int defeats the purpose of using generics.

Answer (score 3):

First, your myArray class shouldn't hold an array of Objects, but rather data of type E:

```
private E[] arr;
```

This should work as long as the files are in the same package:

```
theArray<Integer> myArray = new theArray<>();
```

To add an element should be simple as well (as long as your implemented add method works):

```
myArray.add(1); //adds 1 to the array
```

Let me know if this works as I cannot test it right now. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In order to access an array in a different class you have to assign the array to a object in that class. To do this you would need to build a constructor like such.

```
public void theArray() {
int [] array = {};
}
```

From here you would then be able to call the constructor in your other class and be able to add methods in theArray class to add values to the array. Hope this helps